# Specflow build error using .Net framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, specflow

I have a project that depends on .Net Framework 3.5 and I want to set up specflow tests for it using MsTest as the unit test provider.  I have setup everything as needed in my app config and am thinking that I need to go back to previous versions of specflow.  I have gone back a number of versions (currently at 1.5.0.0) and it is still failing.  I am sure that this should work with 3.5 but cannot get it to.

Here is the error.
Error   6   No overload for method 'Given' takes 4 arguments

When I double click the error it takes me to the feature file.

I have regenerated the feature file code behind numerous times and indeed there are 4 params for the given method being generated.

I can send the feature file and app config if need be.

Has anyone else run into this sort of thing?

Comment: I did some further investigation and am now able to get it to build but I am getting an error when I run the default scenario that I suspect has to do with the version of MsTest (the one that works with .Net 3.5) and the version of SpecFlow not matching up.

Comment: This is the error that I am getting.

Comment: Test method IUL_TestDrivenDevelopment.ViewPendingPolicyDataInZLiFE.SpecFlowFeature1Feature.AddTwoNumbers threw exception: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

Comment: The bottom line is I need to get specflow working in VS2010 using .NetFramework 3.5.  Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I got this figured out.  I needed to set the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework" to CopyLocal True.  For some reason by default it sets it to CopyLocal False which does not work.